# Изменения цвета заднего фона при скролле

Tags: javascript, css, hex

Написал скрипт, который при скролле меняет задний цвет страницы, но вот проблема в том, что туда невозможно добавить код из хекса или имя оттенка цвета.

Чтобы скрипт сработал нужно написать имя (в атрибут `data-color`) цвета типа: `yellow`, `red`, `violet` и т.д. Притом, если в атрибут `data-color` написать имя цвета типа **french rose** (из **[википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors:_A%E2%80%93F)** ), то это не будет работать.

Мне надо задавать цвет хексом. Подскажите, как это можно реализовать, чтобы можно было туда написать цвет хексом или хотя бы имена цветов из ссылки которую я предоставил работали?

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

  // селекторы
  var $window = $(window),
    $body = $('body'),
    $panel = $('.panel');

  //
  var scroll = $window.scrollTop() + ($window.height() / 3);

  $panel.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);


    if ($this.position().top <= scroll && $this.position().top + $this.height() > scroll) {

      // Удаляет все классы с body которые  с классом color-
      $body.removeClass(function(index, css) {
        return (css.match(/(^|\s)color-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
      });

      // добавить класс активному диву
      $body.addClass('color-' + $(this).data('color'));
    }
  });


}).scroll();
```

```css
/* Setting fade transition and default settings */

body {
  color: #000;
  transition: background-color 1s ease;
}


/* panel styles */

.panel {
  /* min height incase content is higher than window height */
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* outline: 10px solid hotpink; */
  /* turn above on to see the edge of panels */
}


/* colours */

.color-violet {
  background-color: #7A4EAB !important;
}

.color-indigo {
  background-color: #4332CF !important;
}

.color-blue {
  background-color: #2F8FED !important;
}

.color-green {
  background-color: #4DCF42 !important;
}

.color-yellow {
  background-color: #FFEA00 !important;
}

.color-orange {
  background-color: #F19031 !important;
}

.color-red {
  background-color: #F2293A !important;
}


/* styling for demo, can ignore */

body {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 120%;
  line-height: 1.618;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -0.05em;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

p {
  max-width: 30em;
  margin-bottom: 1.618em;
}

a {
  color: #4332CF;
}

#header {
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: ease-in-out background-color .6s;
}

#header .logo img {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

#header .nav .nav-panel {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

#header .nav .nav-panel .top-panel {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  color: #3116f8 !important;
}

#header .nav .nav-panel .top-panel span {
  line-height: 1.8;
}

#header .nav .nav-panel .top-panel a {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

#header .nav .nav-panel .top-panel a:hover {
  color: #3116f8 !important;
}

#header .nav .nav-panel .top-panel .langs ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#header .nav .nav-panel .top-panel .langs ul li a span {
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">


  <div class="panel" data-color="yellow">
    <div>
      <h1>Magic scrolling colours</h1>
      <p>Scroll to animate the background colour of the body as a full height panel becomes visible.</p>
      <p>I have tried to comment the code, particurly the JavaScript, as much as possible. I hope it's clear to understand.</p>


    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="panel" data-color="violet">
    <h2>Violet panel</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" data-color="indigo">
    <h2>Indigo panel</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" data-color="blue">
    <h2>Blue panel</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" data-color="green">
    <h2>Green panel</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" data-color="yellow">
    <h2>Yellow panel</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" data-color="orange">
    <h2>Orange panel</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" data-color="red">
    <h2>Red panel</h2>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: что мешает тебе брать цвет из атрибута

Comment: @RomanC из дата атрибута невозможно брать цвет .то есть я пробовал написать туда хексом цвет и взять от туда не получилось

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Записывай цвет в `data-color` без `#`, а потом в JS добавляй при установке цвета обратно. Вроде проблем с этим никаких нет.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

  // селекторы
  var $window = $(window),
    $body = $('body'),
    $panel = $('.panel');

  //
  var scroll = $window.scrollTop() + ($window.height() / 3);

  $panel.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);


    if ($this.position().top <= scroll && $this.position().top + $this.height() > scroll) {
    
      // устанавливаем цвет 
      $body.css('background-color', `#${$(this).data('color')}`);

    }
  });


}).scroll();
```

```css
/* Setting fade transition and default settings */

body {
  color: #000;
  transition: background-color 1s ease;
}


/* panel styles */

.panel {
  /* min height incase content is higher than window height */
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* outline: 10px solid hotpink; */
  /* turn above on to see the edge of panels */
}


/* styling for demo, can ignore */

body {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 120%;
  line-height: 1.618;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -0.05em;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

p {
  max-width: 30em;
  margin-bottom: 1.618em;
}

a {
  color: #4332CF;
}

#header {
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: ease-in-out background-color .6s;
}

#header .logo img {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

#header .nav .nav-panel {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

#header .nav .nav-panel .top-panel {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  color: #3116f8 !important;
}

#header .nav .nav-panel .top-panel span {
  line-height: 1.8;
}

#header .nav .nav-panel .top-panel a {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

#header .nav .nav-panel .top-panel a:hover {
  color: #3116f8 !important;
}

#header .nav .nav-panel .top-panel .langs ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#header .nav .nav-panel .top-panel .langs ul li a span {
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">


  <div class="panel" data-color="FFEA00">
    <div>
      <h1>Magic scrolling colours</h1>
      <p>Scroll to animate the background colour of the body as a full height panel becomes visible.</p>
      <p>I have tried to comment the code, particurly the JavaScript, as much as possible. I hope it's clear to understand.</p>


    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="panel" data-color="7A4EAB">
    <h2>Violet panel</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" data-color="4332CF">
    <h2>Indigo panel</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" data-color="2F8FED">
    <h2>Blue panel</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" data-color="4DCF42">
    <h2>Green panel</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" data-color="FFEA00">
    <h2>Yellow panel</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" data-color="F19031">
    <h2>Orange panel</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" data-color="F2293A">
    <h2>Red panel</h2>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое